# How to post two resources in the same request?

Tags: rest

I have `/companies` and `/users` resources. My business logic prevents creating company without first user. Only way I can think of:

```
POST /companies
{
  "name": "Harvey's Broiler",
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Jojo",
    "lastName": "Stomopolous",
    "email": "jojostomopolous@harveysbroiler.com",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 10001,
  "name": "Harvey's Broiler",
  "user": {
    "id": 10002,
    "firstName": "Jojo",
    "lastName": "Stomopolous",
    "email": "jojostomopolous@harveysbroiler.com"
  }
}
```

Later, they can be reachable as:

```
GET /companies/10001
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 10001,
  "name": "Harvey's Broiler"
}
```

and

```
GET /users/10002
```

or

```
GET /companies/10001/users/10002
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 10002,
  "firstName": "Jojo",
  "lastName": "Stomopolous",
  "email": "jojostomopolous@harveysbroiler.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question developers encounter when designing APIs.

The first question you should ask yourself is are the `Company` and `User` resources same order citizens? By order, I mean are they the same importance, are they both resources you massively operate with and have independent roles and operations in the system you are building? My hunch is the answer is yes. If the answer is no, then the `User` is only a way of denoting the founder of the `Company`, and you have no problem, just put the `User` as an embedded object like you already did.

However, if my hunch is right that you have some business logic around `User` and `Company`, I would do just that, keep them separate, under separate endpoints.

If you need a `User` to create a `Company`, than implement that logic. If a `Company` is attempted to be created with a missing `User`, return an error (HTTP response 400, or something along those lines). Of course, that should be documented for the user. The request is than like this:

```
POST /companies
{
  "name": "Harvey's Broiler",
  "user": 1234
}
```

Mashing the creation of two objects under the same request artifically can only lead to issues. Now you need to return the status for both (a `User` is created, but `Company` failed?), return two IDs (what if you also need to add other information, tax details, you get a third ID) and so on.

The only valid reason for creating the `User` along with the `Company` is if a `User` is very often created along with the `Company`, if not always, and you need to reduce the number of API calls, so you only fire one, but I am not sure that is the case.

If you can't even have a `User` without a `Company`, than see if you can revise the requirements or create the `User`/`Company` in two steps. First fire a request for a `User` "placeholder" (let's say the `User` will not be visible in a list of `User`s or such, it will not be valid), and after creating `Company`, the `User` becomes valid and visible, and other operations become permitted. Until that, there is no `User`, only a placeholder for it. The same can be logic can be reversed for `Company`.

And another thing, I will not go into this kind of nesting:

```
GET /companies/10001/users/10002
```

First, it is usually hard to program (you get a lot of boilerplate), and it is a possible maintenance nightmare. You can extrapolate the case to:

```
GET /companies/10001/users/10002/accounts/24314/bank/address
```

And fetch a bank address for a bank of a user who founded a company. I'm hesitant to implement this kind of approach if I do not have to.

Also, please consider reading about [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). It might help you if you need this kind of nesting. Actually I will always encourage at least considering the HATEOAS principle when starting a new API.

Comment: Well, the point of posting two resources is atomic action. REST is not database wrapper, and we can't rely on client that they will call REST in correct order. So, if you have business logic of "Cannot create company without user", the endpoint should be smart enough to protect the data from any data integrate issues. Since this is posting part, I don't see any help from HATEOAS for in particular logic.

Comment: Well, of course you have to protect the calls. I mean, most of the APIs I worked with have some sort of temporal coupling. For starters, you usually have to authenticate before calling other endpoints.
Nevertheless, if you do wish to keep it as one request, keep in mind that everything is a resource. Create a resource named CompanyFoundation, with attributes, companyInfo and user, and try it like that. On the backend you can create two entities and store them, the company and user.